# Mobile application with Sencha Touch and Django backend

Tags: django, rest, sencha-touch

I'm starting an application which will have an API server and a UI server. The API server will use django rest framework, while the UI server will use Sencha Touch. The API server will accept http requests and send JSONs, while the UI server should accept JSONs and send http requests. I'm just wondering if Sencha Touch has the functionality to accept JSONs, and to send http requests. If it doesn't, then I'm assuming I'll need to run it behind a http server. Please let me know if Sencha touch can do what I need it to do, and if not, what my best alternative is.

p.s. let me know if you need any more info

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with sencha touch, jquery-mobile or a custom configuration of HTML, JS and CSS (e.g. bootstrap, jquery and backbone.js). You could use Django for both the API server and UI server. For the API, please take django-tastypie in consideration as you'll get JSON api's for free. The UI server will be very simple, as you'll be doing most things in the browser. Therefore, you could pick any implementation....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track. See the following help article http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/stores

You basically use Django to serve JSON and sencha on the mobile platform to consume it.

Cheers,

_M